# "is this date the third thursday of the month?" - Java Library?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I've got a few dozen backlog requests in the pipeline like

```
'I need this functionality to run on the third Thursday of every month, and the first Wednesday of every other month...'
```

I've already got a function that runs every day, i just need the: `isThirdSundayOfMonth(date)` bit to append onto then end.

The less time I spend considering the nuances of the Gregorian calendar and timezones, the better my life is.

Anyone know a Java library that simplifies this sort of calculation? No xml config or frameworks or anything. Just a .Jar and a documented, readable API would be perfect.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try `java.util.Calendar`

Comment: Maybe Java 8's new api or Joda Time, although asking for a library is actually considered off-topic for SO.

Comment: But the question is really "how do I do this, I'm willing to use an additional library". And that's completely on-topic for SO.

Comment: @DanielMartin: Agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Complete overview:

**In Java-8 (new standard):**

```
LocalDate input = LocalDate.now(); // using system timezone
int ordinal = 3;
DayOfWeek weekday = DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;

LocalDate adjusted = 
  input.with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(ordinal, weekday));
boolean isThirdSundayInMonth = input.equals(adjusted);
```

**In Joda-Time (popular 3rd-party-library):**

```
LocalDate input = new LocalDate(); // using system timezone
int ordinal = 3;
int weekday = DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY;

LocalDate start = new LocalDate(input.getYear(), input.getMonthOfYear(), 1);
LocalDate date = start.withDayOfWeek(weekday);
LocalDate adjusted = (
  date.isBefore(start)) 
  ? date.plusWeeks(ordinal) 
  : date.plusWeeks(ordinal - 1);
boolean isThirdSundayInMonth = input.equals(adjusted);
```

**Using `java.util.GregorianCalendar` (old standard):**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
GregorianCalendar input = new GregorianCalendar();
int ordinal = 3;
int weekday = Calendar.SUNDAY;

GregorianCalendar start =
    new GregorianCalendar(input.get(Calendar.YEAR), input.get(Calendar.MONTH), 1);
int dow = start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); // Sun=1, Mon=2, ...
int delta = (weekday - dow);
if (delta < 0) {
    delta += 7;
}
start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, delta + (ordinal - 1) * 7);
String comp1 = sdf.format(input.getTime());
String comp2 = sdf.format(start.getTime());
boolean isThirdSundayInMonth = comp1.equals(comp2);
```

Even with the ugliest library a solution is possible ;-) I have used a string comparison in order to get rid of any timezone effects or time-of-day-parts including milliseconds. A field-wise comparison based only on year, month and day-of-month is also a good idea.

**Using Time4J (my own 3rd-party-library):**

```
PlainDate input = 
  SystemClock.inLocalView().today(); // using system timezone
Weekday weekday = Weekday.SUNDAY;

PlainDate adjusted = 
  input.with(PlainDate.WEEKDAY_IN_MONTH.setToThird(weekday));
boolean isThirdSundayInMonth = input.equals(adjusted);
```

Answer (score 1):

The canonical library for all things date and time related is [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Adopt that and purge all the standard java classes like `Date`, `Calendar`, etc.

It will make your life much better.

As for "How do I use joda-time to find the third Thursday of the month", there's [a stackoverflow answer for that already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033167/joda-time-how-to-find-second-thursday-of-month). I'd suggest using the code that the question asker posted and then the question "is it now the third Thursday of the month" is answered by:

```
LocalDate today = new LocalDate();
if (today.equals(calcDayOfWeekOfMonth(DateTimeConstants.THURSDAY, 3, today))) {
    // do special third-Thursday processing here
}
```

Comment: I upvoted but would add that the canonical library is now the `java.time` API in Java 8, which is a reworked Joda-Time.