# How to get a date by giving the week of the month and day of the week

Tags: java, date, calendar, dayofweek, week-number

How do i get a date by giving the week of the month and day of the week.

Example: If i need the third tuesday of November 2018.

Week of month : 3,
Day of Week : 3

Expected date is :  Nov 20 2018

But the value we get is : Nov 13 2018. Since the start day of the month (thursday) is less than than the expected day(tuesday).

```
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
   calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,2018 );  
   calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);  
   calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 3);  
   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 3);  
   System.out.println("Time " + calendar.getTime());
```

How do i get the correct date??

Comment: If you just input the week of month and the day of week, then how do you determine which month it is?

Comment: WEEK_OF_MONTH should be 4. Since 20th falls on 4th week of Nov. Works fine with this value. Tested.

Comment: The `Calendar` class has design problems and is long outdated. Use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. Depending on your definition of week numbers in a month the `WeekFields` class may be useful.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 8, you can do this,

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate input = LocalDate.now();
        int ordinal = 3;
        DayOfWeek weekday = DayOfWeek.THURSDAY;
        TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(ordinal, weekday) ;
        LocalDate adjusted = input.with( ta );
        System.out.println(adjusted.toString());
    }

}
```

I have taken it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712505/is-this-date-the-third-thursday-of-the-month-java-library), and there are more ways to do that in the given link.

Comment: For Java 6 & 7, this functionality can be found in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code :

```
LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(3, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY));
```

This will output :

> 2018-11-20

More info can be found in the java docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Calendar then:

```
int year = 2018;
int month = 10;  // zero based November

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 3);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: These terrible old classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Comment: I know, this is why I prefix my answer: *If you want to use Calendar then*. The other answers cover the modern way.